# having "expected an indented block" in python

Tags: python

[image]

I have no idea what the problem is

Comment: The error message is telling that this `print` statement should be `indented`.  It's very clear. (as well next print statement)

Comment: This question shows no research effort. You should take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: (also, and notably, the code you ran isn't the code you're showing)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. I voted to close your question as a duplicate of a very comprehensive existing question. It should help you understand and fix the problem, though the answer is a bit lengthy. If you still need more specific help, please ask a new question including a [mre] as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341).

Answer (score -1):

its just an indentation error you just have to use print inside if condition

```
if (condition):
     print("xyz")
```